# How to open an app when the power button is pressed

Tags: windows-10, power

I want to run an app when I press the power button.
So that e.g. Notepad will open when I press the power button on my PC instead of just sending a signal to shutdown.
How do I do that? Are there any registry tweaks?

I am on Windows 10 21H1.

Comment: It's not possible

Comment: The Power button is nothing to do with Windows. It is part of the computer hardware and used to be not a key but a mechanical switch (so costs money). Note laptops tend to also have a sleep key. This is part of Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible, OK I would use something else.